# SQL single row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, row, transpose

I have two tables A:

```
COL1 | COL2 | IDS
10   | 2    | 1,2,4
20   | 3    | 1,3
30   | 1    | 1,3,4,6
```

and B:

```
ID | NAME
1  | XYZ
2  | ABC
3  | PQR
4  | STV
5  | LMN
6  | IJK
```

now I have to split rows in table A depending on values inside column IDS. IDS is a column having multiple IDs (present in table B) separated by coma and number of such IDs in a column IDS is not fixed.

after splitting operation each row in A should split into x number of new rows (where x is the number of IDs present in column IDS) and each new row will have same values for COL1 & COL2 for the same row in table A.

the resulting table should look like this:

```
COL1 | COL2 | ID
10   | 2    | 1
10   | 2    | 2
10   | 2    | 4
20   | 3    | 1
20   | 3    | 3
30   | 1    | 1
30   | 1    | 3
30   | 1    | 4
30   | 1    | 6
```

What is the best way to achieve this row transformation?

Comment: Which database do you want to use? E.g. Postgres can `unnest` arrays like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS, this is possibly most easily done by loading your rows in code and re-inserting them.  The RDBMS itself may not have native support for this operation, and it's a good thing you are taking the step to properly normalize the table.